# How to import configurable products?

Tags: configurable-product, import, csv, dataflow

We have imported the simple product using

`system -> Import/Export -> Dataflow profile ->  Import All Products`

We want to associate this product with configurable product. How we will achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data flow doesn't support simple products association, you can use import/export instead it's available since magento 1.5

**System > Import/Export > Import**

Read this article to get more details on how to generate the csv: http://www.magestore.com/how-to-magento-import-configurable-products.html/